# Setting up a local website on wifi router

Tags: mobile, wifi, localhost, conference, captivenetwork

We have a mobile website developed for a conference which should be accessible to users thru smartphone/tablet/laptop when they connect to a wifi router.
Is it possible to setup a xampp server on a local pc connected to the router and assign it a url, so that users can type the url and access the website?
Will the users have to type an ip address or would it be possible to assign a url?
I read in some posts that one way would be to setup a captive portal but we do not have the time & resources to setup a captive portal. Kindly correct me if I am wrong.
Thanks in advance,
Raghav

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this could be possible by building out a DNS server for the lan. And entry for your webserver would then have to be in there. Then, in the router settings, specify the local DNS server as the DNS that gets assigned to other LAN computers via DHCP. Any node that connects to the router and uses DHCP to resolve IP settings should get that DNS server. Then when a client attempts to resolve www.website.com, it will ask the local DNS to resolve it and the request will be translated to the LAN address. I have never done this before but it may be worth a shot.